# Numerical Inverse Z Transform?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-transforms, inverse-function

Is there a way to compute the inverse z-transform in Mathematica numerically? I'm trying to compute the following...

```
f = InverseZTransform[(z*μ*(λ^3*μ - z*λ^3*μ + 3*λ^2*μ^2 - 4*z*λ^2*μ^2 + z^2*λ^2*μ^2 + 3*λ*μ^3 - 3*z*λ*μ^3 + μ^4))/(λ^4*μ - z*λ^4*μ + 4*λ^3*μ^2 - 6*z*λ^3*μ^2 + 2*z^2*λ^3*μ^2 + 6*λ^2*μ^3 - 9*z*λ^2*μ^3 + 
   3*z^2*λ^2*μ^3 + 4*λ*μ^4 - 4*z*λ*μ^4 + μ^5) /. {λ -> 0.75, μ -> 1.}, z, t];
```

---

UPDATE

---

So, I expanded the above polynomial in a power-series and then used the following code to compute the coefficients:

```
 I did try a power series expansion using the following code. The probability function does sum to 1 using the following: f = Total[

Table[ Last[
 CoefficientList[
  Normal[Series[ (
    z \[Mu] (\[Lambda]^3 \[Mu] - z \[Lambda]^3 \[Mu] + 
       3 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^2 - 4 z \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^2 + 
       z^2 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^2 + 3 \[Lambda] \[Mu]^3 - 
       3 z \[Lambda] \[Mu]^3 + \[Mu]^4))/(\[Lambda]^4 \[Mu] - 
     z \[Lambda]^4 \[Mu] + 4 \[Lambda]^3 \[Mu]^2 - 
     6 z \[Lambda]^3 \[Mu]^2 + 2 z^2 \[Lambda]^3 \[Mu]^2 + 
     6 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^3 - 9 z \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^3 + 
     3 z^2 \[Lambda]^2 \[Mu]^3 + 4 \[Lambda] \[Mu]^4 - 
     4 z \[Lambda] \[Mu]^4 + \[Mu]^5), {z, 0, k}]], z]], {k, 1, 
 100}]] /. {\[Lambda] -> 0.75, \[Mu] -> 1.0, k -> 4}

 (* 1. *)
```

So, using the above, it appears to be a proper probability function as the terms generated by the function above sums to 1 if a sufficient number of terms are used.

The mean can be computed and turns out to be 3.05078.

This agrees with my simulation results.

Comment: $$\frac{z \left(\frac{9 z^2}{16}-\frac{315 z}{64}+\frac{343}{64}\right)}{\frac{81 z^2}{32}-\frac{2793 z}{256}+\frac{2401}{256}} $$ is non causal.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the problem is well-posed...

For a rational function, `SeriesCoefficient` will likely work:

```
w = (z*μ*(λ^3*μ - z*λ^3*μ + 3*λ^2*μ^2 - 4*z*λ^2*μ^2 + 
        z^2*λ^2*μ^2 + 3*λ*μ^3 - 3*z*λ*μ^3 + μ^4))/(λ^4*μ - 
      z*λ^4*μ + 4*λ^3*μ^2 - 6*z*λ^3*μ^2 + 2*z^2*λ^3*μ^2 + 
      6*λ^2*μ^3 - 9*z*λ^2*μ^3 + 3*z^2*λ^2*μ^3 + 4*λ*μ^4 - 
      4*z*λ*μ^4 + μ^5) /. {λ -> 3/4, μ -> 1};

SeriesCoefficient[w, {z, Infinity, t}, 
 Assumptions -> t >= 0 && t ∈ Integers]
Table[%, {t, 0, 10}] // N
(*
  {-0.986626, -2.95864, -9.09661, -28.2456, -88.0384, -274.805, 
   -858.257, -2681.03, -8375.66, -26166.8, -81749.8}
*)
```

To achieve a numerically-computed result, the exponent `t` must be given a value.  The results are equivalent to the `SeriesCoefficient` results.

```
f = InverseZTransform[w, z, t];

Table[f /. 
   InverseZTransform[u_, z_, n_] :> 
    NIntegrate[u*z^n*I /. z -> 4 Exp[I*z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 20]/(2 Pi I),
  {t, 0, 10}] /. w_Complex :> Re[w] /; Abs[Im[w]/w] < 10^-14

(*
  {-0.986626, -2.95864, -9.09661, -28.2456, -88.0384, -274.805, 
   -858.257, -2681.03, -8375.66, -26166.8, -81749.8}
*)
```

The path `z -> 4 Exp[I z]` was chosen to encirle the poles:

```
Cases[f, InverseZTransform[u_, z_, n_] :> 
  NSolve@FunctionSingularities[u, z], Infinity]

(*  {{{z -> 1.18598}, {z -> 3.1242}}}  *)
```

That said, I don't know about this area and I assumed the path is in the ROC.  [Cesareo made a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240324/numerical-inverse-z-transform#comment606741_240324) that seems relevant. I don't understand its significance, the comment has been ignored up til now. Perhaps it's not significant.  The [OP made a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240324/numerical-inverse-z-transform#comment606745_240332) that the `InverseZTransform` should be a PDF, which it is clearly not above.  Together, the comments make me wonder whether the problem, in particular `w`, has been defined correctly.

Comment: For context...this polynomial represents the number of customers served during a busy period in a M/M/1/K queue

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you might find useful to know how to numerically integrate ANY complex-valued function in Mathematica.  I'm not familiar with Z-transforms so won't comment on that specifically, but in general, if you have any function $f(z)$ and you wish to integrate it over some contour $z(t)$, from $t_0$ to $t_e$ then simply evaluate:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_e} f(z(t))\frac{dz}{dt}$$  So in your case for $f(z)$, once you determine the contour say $z(t)=re^{it}$, numerically integrate it as:

```
NIntegrate[f[z] (r I Exp[I t])/.z->z[t],{t,0,2 Pi};
```

There are of course issues such as convergence, poles, branch-cuts, etc.

Comment: My function is discrete...so I am not sure if this applies...it could...I just don't know

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a answer your question,but how compute **InverseZTransform** symbolically,not numeric.

```
func = (z*μ*(λ^3*μ - z*λ^3*μ + 
   3*λ^2*μ^2 - 4*z*λ^2*μ^2 + 
   z^2*λ^2*μ^2 + 3*λ*μ^3 - 
   3*z*λ*μ^3 + μ^4))/(λ^4*μ - 
 z*λ^4*μ + 4*λ^3*μ^2 - 
 6*z*λ^3*μ^2 + 2*z^2*λ^3*μ^2 + 
 6*λ^2*μ^3 - 9*z*λ^2*μ^3 + 
 3*z^2*λ^2*μ^3 + 4*λ*μ^4 - 
 4*z*λ*μ^4 + μ^5);

 F = SeriesCoefficient[func /. z -> 1/z, {z, 0, n}] // Simplify(*Analytical Inverse Z-Transform*)

 (*Piecewise[{{μ/(2*λ + 3*μ), 1 + n == 0}, {-(((λ + μ)*(λ^2 + 4*λ*μ + 
 5*μ^2))/(λ*(2*λ + 3*μ)^2)), n == 0}, 
 {(-((λ*μ*(λ + μ)^3*(2*λ + 3*μ)*((((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ - Sqrt[λ^2 + 
 4*μ^2]))/(λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)))^n - 
     (((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ + Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]))/(λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)))^n))/2^n) + 
 2^(-1 - n)*λ*(λ^2 + 4*λ*μ + 3*μ^2)*(λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)*(((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ - 
 Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]))/
      (λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)))^(1 + n) - λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)*(((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ + 
 Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]))/
      (λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)))^(1 + n)) - 2^(-2 - n)*λ^2*μ*
  (λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)*(((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ - Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]))/(λ*μ*(2*λ + 
 3*μ)))^(2 + n) - 
   λ*μ*(2*λ + 3*μ)*(((λ + μ)^2*(λ + 4*μ + Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]))/(λ*μ*(2*λ + 
 3*μ)))^(2 + n)))/
 (λ^2*(λ + μ)^2*(2*λ + 3*μ)*Sqrt[λ^2 + 4*μ^2]), n >= 1}}, 0] *)

 Plot[F /. {λ -> 3/4, μ -> 1}, {n, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here. You have substituted z with 1/z.   In terms of z transform one is doing something similar to Laplace and inverse Laplace transforms but with discrete systems. You seem to have moved from the inside of a circle to the outside or something similar. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Why are you taking the inverse of z?

Comment: @Hugh See here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseZTransform.html. Properties & Relations last line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at your expression in the z-plane we have

```
a = (1.` z (5.359375` - 4.921875` z + 0.5625` z^2))/(
 9.37890625` - 10.91015625` z + 2.53125` z^2)
```

Now I look to see its structure by taking it apart

```
Apart[a]
```

which gives

```
    (* -0.986626 +  0.222222 z
 - 2.88291/(-3.1242 + 1. z) - 0.0757378/(-1.18598 + 1. z) *)
```

This has two real poles but you are going to run into trouble with the first two terms. If we take the inverse z transform term by term the first will give you a single value at the start and the second the derivative of a DiscreteDelta. I am not sure this is defined for a z transform so I am going by the equivalent in a Fourier transform.

The `InverseZTransform` of the poles works fine

```
InverseZTransform[-(
    2.882905166707944`/(-3.1242041285198123` + 1.` z)) - 
   0.07573776119938679`/(-1.1859810566653726` + 1.` z), z, 
  n] // Simplify
```

Giving

[image: Inverse z transform]

We could try to do this numerically but all we would get is a huge value at the start.
Can you define your problem better?

Hope that helps.

Comment: If it exists, the inverse z transform should be a discrete probability distribution and should sum to 1

Comment: Probability is not my area. I use z transforms for time series analysis.  However, can we get to your problem by taking the limit of something that turns your probability distribution from a continuous function into a discrete distribution? As I suggest it looks like you have a delta function and the derivative of a delta function at t = 0.